# How to add line after span tag in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to give line to span tag in javascript.I tried for `<hr>` tag as well but it gives line after span for more understanding here screenshot is attached.

[image: img]

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: `border-bottom: 1px solid black;`?

Comment: yes I use style like  p.style.borderBottomStyle = "solid"; in js file